# Disabling files and directory access through the browser

Tags: debian, browser

A rookie question here:
Is it normal I can access all of my directories and files through the web browser? Isn't this risky and insecure? How can I change it?

I thought only www/var/ directory could be accessed through the browser.

Comment: Are saying you can access files on your server through the browser, or on your file system?

Comment: No, I'm just talking about a local server, but i don't like being able to surf all around my file system through the browser. That's why i ask if it's the normal behaviour or if it should be configured.

Comment: I hadn't seen the Debian tag. But your browser can usually access your file system, regardless of there being a server present. That might be what is happening. Try shutting down the server and see if the behavior continues.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings ?

Comment: I just stopped the service and the behaviour continues. But from what you say this is the normal behaviour right?

Comment: local file browsing is normal, and does not work because of, or related to the web server at all. (regardless of using a directory browser, internet browser, unc, etc.)

Comment: Exactly... you are just accessing your file system through your browser. Just like you can probably access the web through your file explorer (or whatever the name).

Comment: DavidPostill, I understand that that configuration is meant for when the server is accessed remotely right? cause i can see all my root directory in the apache configuration file without 'indexes' word meaning it shoudn't be indexed when trying to access it from the browser.

Comment: RSinohara, please add your comment explaining that file system access through the browser is the normal behaviour as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer since you were the first to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal and safe.

You are acessing your file system through the browser, as is the default behavior for browsers. You could do the same even if there were no server available on your machine.

In the same way, accessing a web address through most file explorers will also work.

What you experience is access that is not passign through the http server, and an outside user (not in your machine) will not be able to access your file system.

FYI, most http servers do have an option to allow listing of files, witch is disabled by default.